# AngularJS order multiple objects array with object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a multiple objects array:

```
{
   "option_12": {
      "id": "0",
      "name": "6 x 330ml",
      "price": "0.00"
   },
   "option_14": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "12 x 330ml",
      "price": "2.00"
   },
   "option_17": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "15 x 330ml",
      "price": "4.00"
   },
   "option_10": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "30 x 330ml",
      "price": "1.00"
   }
}
```

I'm using the AngularJS Filter orderBy attempting to sort the objects by the price value. So in this case, option_12 should be first and option_10 should be second.

In controller:

```
$scope.pOptions = $filter('orderBy')($scope.pOptions, 'price');
```

In my view where I am populating select options using ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="SelectedPOption" ng-options="option.name for option in pOptions|orderBy:'price'"></select>
```

Neither of these have any effect. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup for `select` is fine. It's the array that has a few problems.

- Don't use quotes for keys in js.
- Price should be numeric to sort correctly
- Enclose all elements of the array using `[]`
- Don't call `filter` from js since you call it from the markup.

Example:

```
$scope.pOptions = [{
    id: "0",
    name: "6 x 330ml",
    price: 0.00
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "12 x 330ml",
    price: 2.00
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "15 x 330ml",
    price: 4.00
}, {
    id: 1,
    name: "30 x 330ml",
    price: 1.00
}];
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/n09iupr70zRX56kVrYK9?p=preview

**EDIT:** Since the data arrives like that from the backend API you can iterate the object keys/properties and use map to project the sub-objects to an array:

```
$scope.pOptions = Object.keys($scope.pOptions).map(function(k) {
   var obj = $scope.pOptions[k];
   obj.price = parseFloat(obj.price);
   return obj;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried out the working example. Firstly, I wasn't using the filter in both controller and view - that was just to show what I had tried in both. I tried manipulating the data in your working example to see where exactly it's going wrong. The price and keys being in quotes does not seem to make a difference. Problem is my objects are not enclosed in an array and have names eg '"option_10": '. That's how the data is received from the API -  how can i correct this?

Comment: Just as you answered I managed with forEach like so:
       $scope.pOptions = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.pOptions_, function(option) {
          $scope.pOptions.push(option);
        });

Comment: It's almost always great to have options :-)